# The direct limit of invertible functions on a variety

Tags: limits-colimits, galois-cohomology

Let $X$ be a smooth geometrically integral variety over a number field $k$. We denote by $\bar{k}[X]^*$ the group of invertible functions on $\bar{X}$, and let $$G = \varinjlim_{n \in \mathbb{Z}_{>0}}I_n$$
where $I_n=\bar{k}[X]^*$ for all $n$ and for $m$ such that $m|n$, we have $$I_m \rightarrow I_n:\bar{k}[X]^* \rightarrow \bar{k}[X]^*:x \mapsto x^{n/m}.$$
**Question 1.** How do we show that this direct limit is $\bar{k}[X]^* \otimes_\mathbb{Z} \mathbb{Q}$? Most examples of computing direct limits are related to multiplicative maps between $\mathbb{Z}$, so I'm struggling to find any similarities in methods.

Furthermore, we have
$$H^i(k,\bar{k}[X]^*\otimes \mathbb{Q}) \cong H^i(k,\bar{k}[X]^*) \otimes \mathbb{Q},$$ where $H^i(k,-)$ denotes the Galois cohomology functor.

**Question 2.** How do we compute $H^0(k,\bar{k}[X]^*)$, i.e., the invertible functions fixed by Galois action?

**Question 3.** I believe that $H^i(k,\bar{k}[X]^*)$ is torsion for $i \geq 1$, is there any direct way to show this?